Как добавлять пустые массивы в файл .env правильно?
Добавил в конфиг appsettigs.json секцию:
"SystemsConfiguration": {  
  "Systems": { 
    "System1": {
      "Entities": [] 
     },    
     "System2": { 
       "Entities": []    
     }, 
    "System3": {      
       "Entities": [ "some1", "some2" ] 
    }  
  } 
}  

Как мне правильно указать пустые массивы в .env файле, чтобы все корректно работало ?
То есть чтобы значения для System1 и System2 реально были, но массивы у них были пустые.
Таким образом?
SystemsConfiguration__Systems__System1__Entities__0=
SystemsConfiguration__Systems__System2__Entities__0=
SystemsConfiguration__Systems__System3__Entities__0=some1
SystemsConfiguration__Systems__System3__Entities__1=some2


На английском SO предлагают дефолтно инициализировать эти поля нужным вам образом: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69543455/8324991

@CrazyElf я так и делаю в коде, но мне обязательно нужно в .env добавить. И я не знаю что туда писать

Кажется никак, почитайте это: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-9.0
